# Theoretical question regarding characteristic polynomial and cyclical functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am new to Differential Equations, and I would like to gain the following understanding:

Say we have a matrix $\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$, where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers. Would it be correct to state that if the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf{A}$ is of the form $λ^2+α^2$ (where α is a real number, not equal to 0), $\mathbf{all}$ solutions to $\mathbf{x'}=\mathbf{Ax}$ will be cyclical?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, because this means that the eigenvalues are purely imaginary, implying oscillatory motion.

Comment: @josh b.
Thank you! The reason I was doubting is because of the 0-vector. What is your take on that?

Comment: The only caveat to this is if the initial condition is the zero vector, then the solution is constant, as opposed to oscillatory. Otherwise, there shouldn’t be an issue.